# Authenication fail during root on AT&T Galaxy AT&T SGH-I337 using Odin in 4.3

Tags: rooting, root-access

My mp3 player was socks when played music file and hang device.so

I have try to root my Galaxy S4 AT&T SGH-I337 using Odin, but failed. I am getting these

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> CF-Auto-Root-jflte-jfltexx-gti9505.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin v.3 engine (ID:3)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> recovery.img
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> FAIL! (Auth)
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Anyone help me, how to root this device.

Comment: What firmware are you running? MDL, MK2, MF3? Please add the build number to your question.

Comment: Keeping this question open, as the answer is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The file you downloaded "CF-Auto-Root-jflte-jfltexx-gti9505.tar.md5" is not designed for the device you are trying to use it on.  GT-I9505 is the international model, and is different from your AT&T model SGH-I337.  Any rooting methods must be tailored for your exact device model.

I recommend heading to the [section](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-att) dedicated to your specific device on XDA-Developers forums and reading up on guides and how-to's.  Specifically, [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41548391&postcount=2) post lists several rooting methods, depending on your phone's currently installed firmware/baseband version.